# How to make search in HTML5

Tags: html, search

I want to make search field in HTML5. This is my code:

```css
input[type="search"] {
 -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
 box-sizing: content-box;
 -webkit-appearance: searchfield;
}
```

```html
<input class="search" type="search" placeholder="Search ... " />
```

It's showing the search input but how to make it "search"? Should I use Javascript or what?

Comment: what do you mean by to make it "to search"? is it like searching and fetching actual results?

Comment: Yes. I want if you search a word from my page, to show it. Like if you search somewhere, e.g. in a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
$("body *:contains('" + "YOURWORD" + "')").each( function() { ... });
```

The rest of the functionality and how to handle it; I leave to you.

Comment: Oh and do you care to elaborate why you down vote this answer ?

Comment: The reason you chose this question as off-topic is merely based on your subjective determination. The question is clear, and even tho it might not sound like a usual thing to do, there's nothing wrong with asking it. If you deem to down-vote all questions that don't fit your programming morale then rather comment on it than just down voting it. Finally what people say on Meta is far from always correct. I hope you'll be more reasonable in your future approach of judging questions. SO is to help people, not to judge them or how they approach solution and guide them where we can.

Comment: The question is not clear, as there is no explanation of what must be searched, how it should be searched or what the search result should be. You made some wild assumptions and then provided an answer. Why do you think the content to be searched are hosted on the page (versus other pages, a database or a JSON object)? Why do you think the search results should be HTML elements (rather than string index positions)? Why do you think the search string should be literal versus tokenized? Why do you assume that jQuery is appropriate (and make no mention of it)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for the more-or-less "official" stance: "*Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which... are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem; require too much guidance for you to answer in full, or request answers to multiple questions.*" Your answer, "*The rest of the functionality and how to handle it; I leave to you.*" shows that this questions runs afoul of "requires too much guidance".